Sample complexity bounds of $L_S(h)$
Fix $\mathscr{H} \subset \mathscr{Y}^\mathscr{X}$ and a loss $\ell : \hat{Y} \times Y \to [0,1]$. Fix $S \in (\mathscr{X} \times \mathscr{Y})^{2m}$. Assume for now that $S$ is not random. Suppose we generate from $S$ two samples $S_1, S_2 \in (\mathscr{X} \times \mathscr{Y})^{m}$ as follows. For each $1 \leq i \leq m$, w.p. $1/2$ we put the $(2i)$’th example in $S_1$ and the $(2i - 1)$’th example in $S_2$, and w.p. $1/2$ we put the $(2i)$’th example in $S_2$ and the $(2i - 1)$’th example in $S_1$. Fix some $h^* \in \mathscr{H}$, and let $\hat{h} \in \mathscr{H}$ be a function that minimizes $L_{S_1} (\hat{h})$.
We want to show that,
$$\Bbb{P}(L_{S_2}(\hat{h})\geq L_S(h^*)+\epsilon) \leq \pi_{2m}(\mathscr{H})e^{-\frac{\epsilon^2 m}{16 (2L_S(h^*) +\epsilon/2)}}$$

My partial answer:
Assume that we have $L_{S_2}(h)$ is $\sqrt{2L_S(h)}$-SubGaussian and that $L_{S_1}(h^*)-L_{S_1}(h)$ is $\sqrt{2(L_S(h)+L_S(h^*))}$-SubGaussian. Then, using the Hodeffing's inequality, we get:

if $L_S(h^*) + \epsilon/2 \geq L_S(h)$, then
$$
\Bbb{P}(L_{S_2}(h)\geq L_S(h^*)+\epsilon) \leq e^{-\frac{(L_S(h^*)-L_S(h)+\epsilon)^2 m}{4 L_S(h)}} \leq e^{-\frac{\epsilon^2 m}{16 (L_S(h^*) +\epsilon/2)}}
$$
if $L_S(h^*) + \epsilon/2 \leq L_S(h)$, then
$$
\Bbb{P}(L_{S_1}(h)\leq L_{S_1}(h^*)) \leq e^{-\frac{(L_S(h) - L_S(h^*))^2 m}{4(L_S(h) + L_S(h^*))}} \leq e^{-\frac{\epsilon^2 m}{16 (2L_S(h^*) +\epsilon/2)}}
$$

But I am stuck here, can someone know how to use the above to show:
$$
\Bbb{P}(L_{S_2}(\hat{h})\geq L_S(h^*)+\epsilon) \leq \pi_{2m}(\mathscr{H})e^{-\frac{\epsilon^2 m}{16 (2L_S(h^*) +\epsilon/2)}}
$$
